# How to disable current date from from input?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using date range picker but i need to disable current date from input please help me how can disable ? thanks

**Note:-** Only I want to show placeholder instead of this 19-11-2021 - 19-11-2021

[image]

**jquery**

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    /*Document is Ready */
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // =============================================
      // DATEPICKER
      // =============================================
      var disabledDates = function(date) {
        var formatted = date.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
      }
      $('.datepicker').daterangepicker({

        locale: {
          format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',

        },

        isInvalidDate: disabledDates
      }, function(label) {});

      $(".calendar.left .daterangepicker_input").before("<div class='calendar-title'> Check Inn </div>");
      $(".calendar.right .daterangepicker_input").before("<div class='calendar-title'>Check Out</div>");

    });
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Documentation provides lots of example, https://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples scroll down to see more examples.

Comment: Which date picker are you using?  Please [edit] and create a snippet with all the required `<script src=` and some basic html so we can see it (not-working) in action.  It's likely a simple fix.